# Install header-only library with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py, header-only

I have a header-only C++ library that I use in my Python extensions. I would like to be able to install them to Python's include path, such that I can compile extensions very easily with `python3 setup.py build`. I'm partly able, but there are two things that I cannot get working (see below):

1. How can I use `python3 setup.py install` to install the header files? Currently I only get some `*.egg` file, but not the headers installed.
2. How can I retain the module's file structure? Currently the file structure is erroneously flattened.

#### What works

With the following `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name        = 'so',
   description = 'Example',
   headers     = [
      'so.h',
   ],
)
```

I can upload the module to PyPi:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
twine upload dist/*
```

and then install it using pip:

```
pip3 install so
```

On my system then I then find the header here

```
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/so/so.h
```

which is available when I compile the extensions with Python.

#### How can I use 'python3 setup.py install'?

Using this strategy I cannot simply run

```
python3 setup.py install
```

In that case some `so*.egg` is installed, but the headers are not stored somewhere where they are available to the compiler.

#### How to retain a file structure?

When the module is a bit more complicated, and there is some directory hierarchy I also run to problems. For the following `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name        = 'so',
  description = 'Example',
  headers     = [
    'so.h',
    'so/implementation.h',
  ],
)
```

The problem is that the headers are installed to

```
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/so/so.h
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/so/implementation.h
```

thus flattening the original file structure.

*How can I fix both issues?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I use `python3 setup.py install` to install the header files?

Unfortunately, you can't as long as you're using `setuptools`. What happens under the hood when you call `setuptools.setup()`? An egg installer is being built (`bdist_egg` command) and installed (via `easy_install`), and neither `bdist_egg` nor `easy_install` support including/installing headers. Although the `distribution` object carries the headers info, it is never requested during the `install` command. This is an old well-known problem that was never resolved because apparently, installation of header files doesn't fit into the egg build/install procedure.

You thus have three options (or at least three options I know of). Two of them (both inducing a switch to `distutils`) are not recommended and are provided for completeness sake only:

#### Bare `distutils` install (not recommended)

```
$ sed 's/from setuptools import setup/from distutils.core import setup/' setup.py
```

This way, the good ol' `distutils` will take care of the installation when doing `python setup.py install`, no egg installer will be built and `install_headers` will be invoked. However, this also includes giving up all the features of `setuptools` including additional keyword args in `setup()` and all the other good stuff, needless to say that packages installed via `distutils` can't be uninstalled with `pip`.

#### `old-and-unmanageable` install (not recommended)

Run the installation with

```
$ python setup.py install --old-and-unmanageable
```

This is a switch `setuptools` provides if you explicitly wish to run the `distutils` install. The egg installer is not built, instead, the `distutils.command.install.install` is invoked. Thus, the installation is the same as with bare `distutils` install.

Drawbacks of this approach: same as with bare `distutils` install plus: `setuptools` condemns usage of the switch; if you forget to provide it, you end with installing eggs and have to redo the installation.

#### Replace `python setup.py install` with `pip install` (recommended)

`pip` is capable of installing packages from source directories; just issue

```
$ pip install dir/
```

assuming `dir` contains the `setup.py`. This way, a wheel file is built from sources (same as in `bdist_wheel`; actually, this command is being run first) and installed, managing the installation of header files just fine.

> How can I retain the module's file structure?

You will have to tweak the `install_headers` command a bit:

```
import os
from distutils.command.install_headers import install_headers as install_headers_orig
from setuptools import setup

class install_headers(install_headers_orig):

    def run(self):
        headers = self.distribution.headers or []
        for header in headers:
            dst = os.path.join(self.install_dir, os.path.dirname(header))
            self.mkpath(dst)
            (out, _) = self.copy_file(header, dst)
            self.outfiles.append(out)

setup(
    name='so',
    headers=['h1.h', 'subtree/h2.h'],
    cmdclass={'install_headers': install_headers},
    ...
)
```

What is essential here is the line

```
dst = os.path.join(self.install_dir, os.path.dirname(header))
```

The vanilla `install_headers` [copies the header files directly to `install_dir`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/install_headers.py#L40); the above line in the overloaded `install_headers` command additionally takes care of the eventual subdirectories in header filenames. When installing the package, the subdirectories should be retained now:

```
$ pip show -f so | grep include
  ../../../include/site/python3.6/so/h1.h
  ../../../include/site/python3.6/so/subtree/h2.h
```

Comment: You may also find useful: [related issue](https://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue142) in Python's bug tracker. I guess nothing changed since 2012...

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for you clear answer! Am I correct in observing that the headers can only be in the same folder as `setup.py` or down from it? E.g. `../src/so.h` would not work? Also can I equally use `pip` to upload the package including the headers to PyPi? How should I do that?

Comment: The files may be located outside of the project directory and even lie in some system dir (I actually have to maintain an obscure project that copies headers from `/usr/include/`).

Comment: But: you have to be careful with relative paths like `../src/so.h` because they will be resolved relative to the working directory, and it is not necessarily the one containing `setup.py`. For example, I can run the script from any other working directory: `cd / && python /home/me/myproj/setup.py cmd`. You are on the safe side if you either specify the absolute paths, or at least resolve the relative ones against some fixed location, for example `__file__` (this would be the path to `setup.py` script).

Comment: As for your other question - you can build wheels with `pip wheel` command, but there is nothing for uploading the packages. However, the build process you described it in your question (`bdist_wheel` + `twine upload`) is the correct one, I usually use the same command to build and push a package to PyPI. I wouldn't change that. BTW, this is also the recommended way by the PyPA devs, [according to these docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#upload-your-distributions).

Comment: I see. I tried resolving it against `__file__` (with `os.path.join(__file__, name)`), but that in my case evaluates to some obscure location: `/private/var/folders/11/qf0tz9ws1q39bj4m993xnt0w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gz4u8q21/setup.py/../src/so.h`, which is not the folder where my library is in??

Comment: Hmm, indeed `pip install .` copies the whole source dir to temp and builds from there, so all relative paths are broken even relative to `__file__`. I guess you have to work with absolute paths then. If you don't like the hardcoded absolute include path in your setup script, you could at least make it configurable - maybe passing the include root in an environment variable or store it in a config file?

Comment: If there are no robust options indeed it is really a matter of taste. I guess I can slightly change the file-structure for this project. Thanks once again!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: `distutils` is deprecated. See [PEP632](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/). This must not be used. What directive must I use to include header files in the `tar.gz` file produced by `python3 -m build` ?

Comment: @chmike I have not recommended `distutils` in the answer long before it was deprecated ;-) as for your question, you can't, as `setuptools` doesn't support passing headers via `setup.cfg`.

Comment: @hoefling you are right that we can't with setuptools. In the mean time I found out that `python3 -m build` is using `sdist` to create the `tar.gz` file. It won't include header files by default. A MANIFEST.in file is required. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.